# Can I install Microsoft Office 2010 on multiple computers?

Tags: installation, license, microsoft-office-2010

I bought Office 2010. You can install it on a pc and a laptop. I don't have a laptop, but do my work from my home computer as well. Can I install it on my home computer instead of the laptop?

Comment: Maybe you should change title to something more on topic?

Comment: Can someone edit the title. It should be "Microsoft Office 2010 Multiple Installation"

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep within the terms of the [licence agreement](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/redir/XT101817772.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA101817777), then no.

It states:

> INSTALLATION AND USE RIGHTS.
>
> a. One Copy per Device. You may install one copy of the software on one device. That device is the "licensed device."
>
> b. Licensed Device. You may only use one copy of the software on the licensed device at a time.
>
> c. Portable Device. You may install another copy of the software on a portable device for use by the single primary user of the licensed device.

If you aren't bothered about keeping to your side of the agreement, then there is probably only going to be a problem if Bill Gates gets bored in his retirement and comes round to your house and tries to force you, at gunpoint, to prove that all your licences are legitimate.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this info?  I always assumed the Office agreement was the same as Windows, one license, one machine.

Comment: Link added, although that isn't where I got it from. You are obviously not a very trusting person.

Comment: I believed you, I just wanted to read it for myself :)  Thanks for the link, and good answer.

Comment: Your work computer is probably not a mainframe fixed to the building it is in, which makes it portable. There is no say if has to have batteries or built in display... But yes, it is a bit of bending of the intended meaning. :)